# sending curl command using java 8

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot

Below is my code in which I am trying to send a curl command to the indicated url but using java but when I run the code it won't execute and sends a curl command please help to fix it or tell me where i did wrong:

```
String command="curl 'http://ipaddress:port/smshttpquery/qs?REQUESTTYPE=SMSSubmitReq&USERNAME=myapp&PASSWORD=app&PHON=XXXXXXXXX&MESSAGE=TEST&ADDRESS=MYAPP&TYPE=4'";
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder=new ProcessBuilder(command.split(" "));
    try {
        processBuilder.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The linux command I want to run is

```
curl 'http://ipaddress:port/smshttpquery/qs?REQUESTTYPE=SMSSubmitReq&USERNAME=myapp&PASSWORD=app&PHON=XXXXXXXXX&MESSAGE=TEST&ADDRESS=MYAPP&TYPE=4'
```

Comment: Do you get any error? Are you sure that curl.exe/sh is accessable from your working directory? Have you tried running your curl command in cmd/terminal?

Comment: What makes you to use this way? Use RestTemplate or WebClient.

Comment: in fact that command is sent to a url that triggers sms to be sent , when I run that command the sms is sent, but when i use Java to run it, nothing happens. curl 'http://ipaddress:port/smshttpquery/qs?REQUESTTYPE=SMSSubmitReq&USERNAME=myapp&PASSWORD=app&PHON=XXXXXXXXX&MESSAGE=TEST&ADDRESS=MYAPP&TYPE=4'

Comment: To track down what is wrong you can replace the command with "touch ~/testfile.txt" and check it it is created. If not, the command is not run. Next you can send your message to some host where you can check the log files.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you showed us all of your code, you won't see any result simply because your code nowhere reads the output stream of the process (process.getInputStream()).

There are other pitfalls on the way to success, though.

Comment: as I said, when I run the command in terminal the sms has to be sent which is done perfectly. but I have a requirement to integrate that command in my java app to which i have done and use ProcessBuilder but nothing happens. can you help me with best way to do or a mistake i did, because I don't see why i will need output stream while the command help me to trigger sms to be sent.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String HttpCall(String link) throws IOException{
    String response = "";
    String beginPoint = link;
    URL url = new URL(beginPoint);

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"))) {
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            response += line;
        }
        reader.close();
        response = response.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
    }
    return response;
```

}